# Bootstrap Form FIle input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with my form. The browse button in the file input can't be seen as a whole. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

And my code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-image fa-fw"></i> Photo List </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">

      <form action="upload-photo.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="file">Upload Photo</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
          <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
        </div>
      <button type="submit" name="uploadp_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Upload!</button>
      </form> <hr />

      </div>
    </div>
```

Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Something's gotta be missing from your code. When I load it, everything looks okay: http://www.bootply.com/0XIUcYJvGW

Comment: @TomNolan, I checked your bootply and it looks the same as my screenshot. Maybe it's my monitor size

Comment: Out of curiosity, what browser and version are you using?

Comment: Firefox 40.0.3 @TomNolan

Comment: I just loaded it in Firefox and now I see your issue. I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your style sheet:

```
.form-control{
    height: auto;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/NMVB2TeaK2

Tested that one in Chrome and Firefox, seems to be working!

Comment: Sure will do it in a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use class name 'filestyle' instead of 'form-control'

```
<input class="filestyle" type="file" id="file" name="files[]" 
       multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
```